# View not visible on navigation on page-refresh

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, durandal

I am using **Durandal 2.0.1**, currently I am facing one issue while refreshing the page.

On refresh I am trying to navigate to previous route with help of `navigateback` function, based on some conditions. The `navigateback` function is called in the activate method.

The problem I am facing is that my view is not visible because `div` below is having `display: none;`, may be because of hide and show done in composition.js

```
<div class="durandal-wrapper" data-view="reports" data-active-view="true" style="display: none">
```

If I am delaying the `navigateback` function then the view is visible.

Can anyone suggest me something to resolve this issue?

Comment: I came across a somewhat similar situation and the only way I could solve it was by having an extra wrapper `<div>` on my view.

Comment: Your view will not be made visible before activate is done. However, you are not really making clear why this is a problem in your situation, what you expect to happen and how this differs from that expectation.

Comment: @Hans,
I have a form, i just want to navigate to previous route if page is refreshed for some reason. 
I am not able to achieve this in any of the life cycle event of the durandal.
The navigation is happening but the composed view is having display as none. If I make display as block or something else, the composed view is visible.